# Copy vector (returned from a function) into a specific point of another vector directly at function call without needing extra temp variables [c++]

Tags: c++, arrays, function, return

I have a function that returns a vector and I want all of that vector inserted into another vector at a specific point directly when calling that function.

What I would like to do is something like this:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

typedef vector<double> Double1D;

Double1D myFunction(Double1D vector, int vector_size){
       Double1D result;
       result.resize (vector_size, 0);
       result = vector; //here is where I would do calculations
       return result;
}

int main()
{
    int vector_size1 = 3;
    int vector_size2 = 6;
    Double1D vector_results;
    vector_results.resize (9, 3);

vector_results[0-2] = myFunction(randomvector, vector_size1);
vector_results[3-8] = myFunction(randomvector2, vector_size2);
```

At the moment I am doing this which needs a for loop and needs extra temporary variables (minimal reproducible example):

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

typedef vector<double> Double1D;

Double1D myFunction(Double1D vector, int vector_size){
       Double1D result;
       result.resize (vector_size, 0);
       result = vector;  //here is where I would do calculations
       return result;
}

int main()
{
    int vector_size1 = 3;
    int vector_size2 = 6;
    Double1D vector_results;
    vector_results.resize (9, 3);
    Double1D vector1 ;
    vector1.resize (vector_size1, 0);
    Double1D vector2 ;
    vector2.resize (vector_size2, 0);

    Double1D temp_vector1 = myFunction(vector1, vector_size1);
    Double1D temp_vector2 = myFunction(vector2, vector_size2);
    
    for (int i = 0; i < (vector_size1 + vector_size2); i++){
       if (i < vector_size1) vector_results[i] = temp_vector1[i];
       if (i < vector_size2) vector_results[i+vector_size1] = temp_vector2[i];
       cout<<vector_results[i]<<endl;
    }  
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: _":I have a function that returns a Double1D array"_ What is a "Double1D array"?  Is that something that you defined?  It doesn't seem to be an array, as arrays don't have member functions.

Comment: Post real code please (that's all bogus stuff, which will never compile), ideally a [mcve], which reproduces your actual problem. To work with fixed size arrays in c++ use `std::array<T,Size>`, for variable length arrays use `std::vector<T>` and all your problems will be gone.

Comment: Thanks for the comments I have found out that Double1D is a vector of doubles from include <vector>, Im gonna try to create a reproducible example but maybe someone already knows the commands I am looking for.

Comment: I have added a reproducible example now

Comment: Aside: `result.resize (vector_size, 0);` seems pointless when you immediately assign `vector` on the next line. `myFunction` could be the one-liner `return vector;` as it is

Comment: Just did that so that it runs for the minimal reproducible example, my function is 200 lines of code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

G'day, Alex from the past. This is you from the future. Here is how you solved it.

The function you want to use is a vector function called: insert() or a more efficient way that works for you  is using copy() with back_inserter().
copy with back_inserter can only insert the vector to the back, whereas insert allows to insert anywhere. Both increase the size of the vector automatically.

Disclaimer: This may not be the best solution I am not an expert.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

//vector<double> is variable that is a vector of doubles
typedef vector<double> Double1D; //this basically just gives vector<double> the name Double1D to make it easier to write

Double1D myFunction(Double1D vector, int vector_size){
       Double1D result; 
       result.resize (vector_size, 0);
       result = vector;  //here is where I would do calculations
       return result;
}

int main()
{
    int vector_size1 = 3;
    int vector_size2 = 6;
    Double1D vector_results(vector_size1+vector_size2, 0);//fill vector with vector_size1+vector_size2 many 0s
    Double1D vector1(vector_size1,1) ;//fill vector with vector_size1 many 1s
    Double1D vector2(vector_size2, 2) ; //fill vector with vector_size2 many 1s
    for (int i = 0; i < vector_results.size(); i++){ //see that it is full of 0s
       cout<<vector_results[i]<<" ";
    }  
    cout<<endl;
    
//this is specifically what you asked for
    vector_results = myFunction(vector1, vector_size1); //vector_results is now just a copy of the vector of the output of the function
    for (int i = 0; i < vector_results.size(); i++){
      cout<<vector_results[i]<<" ";
    }  
    cout<<endl;
    //yourvectorname.insert(where to insert (an iterator), what to insert beginning, what to insert end)
    //vector_results.insert(vector_results.begin()+3, myFunction(vector2, vector_size2).begin(), myFunction(vector2, vector_size2).end()); //this doesnt work as I think the function gets called twice?
    Double1D temp_vec = myFunction(vector2, vector_size2); 
    vector_results.insert(vector_results.begin()+vector_size1, temp_vec.begin(), temp_vec.end()); 
    for (int i = 0; i < vector_results.size(); i++){
      cout<<vector_results[i]<<" ";
    }  
    cout<<endl;   
    
//here is a version using back_inserter which I have read is more efficient
    //whatever you want at the start you just overwrite the destined vector with it
    vector_results = myFunction(vector1, vector_size1); //vector_results is now just a copy of the vector of the output of the function
    //create a tempvector to be able to use it
    Double1D temp_vec2 = myFunction(vector2, vector_size2);
    //now the important part: copy(start of what you wanna copy,end of what you wanna copy, where you want to insert it)
    copy(temp_vec2.begin(), temp_vec2.end(), back_inserter(vector_results)); //back_inserter inserts it at the back (and from what I read more efficient than an insert in the middle)
    for (int i = 0; i < vector_results.size(); i++){
       cout<<vector_results[i]<<" ";
    }
    cout<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The idiomatic method for writing a range of results is to take [*OutputIterators*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/OutputIterator) as function parameters.

```
#include <vector>

using Double1D = std::vector<double>;

void myFunction(Double1D::iterator dFirst, Double1D::iterator dLast) {
    int n = /* number between 0 and dLast - dFirst */
    dFirst[n] = /* calculations */

    // or

    for (; dFirst != dLast; ++dFirst) {
        *dFirst = /* calculation */
    }
}

int main() {
    Double1D array_results;
    array_results.resize(9, 0);
    myFunction(randomvector, vector_size1);
    myFunction(randomvector1, vector_size2);
}
```

If you insist on assigning a `Double1D` to something:

```
class AssignableSlice {
    Double1D::iterator first;
    Double1D::iterator last;
public:
    AssignableSlice(Double1D & values, size_t first, size_t last)
      : first(values.begin() + first), last(values.begin() + last) {}

    AssignableSlice& operator=(Double1D & other) {
        if (other.size() != std::distance(first, last)) throw std::out_of_range("wrong size in assignment");

        std::copy(other.begin(), other.end(), first, last);
        return *this;
    }
};

int main() {
    Double1D vector1;
    vector1.resize (vector_size1, 0);
    Double1D vector2;
    vector2.resize (vector_size2, 0);
    Double1D array_results;
    array_results.resize(9, 0);
    AssignableSlice(array_results, 0, vector_size1) = myFunction(vector1, vector_size1);
    AssignableSlice(array_results, vector_size1, vector_size1 + vector_size2) = myFunction(vector2, vector_size2);
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. Unfortunately I did not see it while I was editing the reproducable example into my answer and I had changed all isntances of array to vector in case someone might be wondering why it is not the same.

Comment: I think I cannot use your answer since I do not want to pass vector_results to the function nor edit it directly inside the function.

Comment: Thanks for your edit. I am writing this function inside quite a big project and do not want to wirte a class as I only have to do this twice inside the code. I feel like the std::copy command is what I want, I am going to try implementing it